# Using setdiff() on groups of a group without for looping

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` :

```
    id year groupid
1   A1 2000      G1
2   A1 2000      G1
3   A1 2000      G1
4   A2 2000      G2
5   A1 2001      G1
6  A12 2001      G1
7  A13 2001      G1
8   A3 2001      G2
9  A33 2001      G2
10  A4 2001      G3
11  A4 2002      G3
12  A5 2002      G3
13  A5 2003      G2
14  A6 2003      G4
```

What I would like to do is to use `setdiff()` between values with the same `groupid` of two consecutive years.

Example :

For the year 2000, `G1` has one `id` : `A1`. For the year 20001, `G1` has three different `id` : `A1`, `A12`, `A13`. So when `setdiff()` is applied between those two, it will return `2`. Between the year 2001 and 2002, since `G1` is not present in the year 2002, the value `0` will be given. For the same `groupid`, if two years are not consecutive, the value given will be either `0` if the group is not present in the second year or the number of the different `id`.

Expected results :

```
   year groupid newid
1  2000    G1    1
2  2000    G2    1
3  2000    G3    0
4  2000    G4    0
5  2001    G1    2
6  2001    G2    2
7  2001    G3    1
8  2001    G4    0
9  2002    G1    0
10 2002    G2    0
11 2002    G3    2
12 2002    G4    0
13 2003    G1    0
14 2003    G2    1
15 2003    G3    0
16 2003    G4    1
```

I have done this with a `for loop`, some `if()` and `dplyr` functions but since I have a lot of rows, it took a bit too much time (around 5 minutes). So I'm searching to replace the loop by some `dplyr` functions or `data.table` functions to do this task if less time.

Data :

```
structure(list(id = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A1", "A12", "A13", 
"A3", "A33", "A4", "A4", "A5", "A5", "A6"), year = c(2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 
2003), groupid = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G1", "G1", "G1", 
"G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G2", "G4")), .Names = c("id", 
"year", "groupid"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT : Modified the example

Comment: Can you post your solution as well please?

Comment: if 'G1_2001' would be `c("A","B")` and `G1_2002` would be `c("B","C")` you want the function to return 1, right?

Comment: @JannaMaas yeah the order doesn't matter with setdiff()

Comment: I removed my answer since I misunderstood your question. Could you please change your example to illustrate such overlaps between consecutive years? Your current one doesn't

Comment: @Aurèle I don't get what you're saying. What part did you not understand ?

Comment: In your example, `intersect()` between two consecutive years, for any given `groupid`, is always empty. That caused my (simple) solution (and @jogo's as well if I'm not mistaken) to be valid for your example, but not in your general case

Comment: so this is actually two steps: firstly, you need to add any missing year-groupId combinations; and then you need to perform a setdiff(nextYear, thisYear) for each groupId. Yes?

Comment: @Aurèle Oh yeah I edited the example for that. I have a same id for two consecutive years for a same group.

Comment: @JannaMaas Yeah that's how the algorithm works. For two consecutive years, between all the unique `groupid` of the dataframe, I need to `setdiff` them. So if I have the same `groupid` for `thisYear` and `NextYear`, I use `setdiff`, if I have only the `groupid` for `thisYear`, it returns 0, if I have only the groupid for `NextYear`, I use `length()`

Comment: can you double check your expected results?

Comment: @chinsoon12 The expected results are correct, check if you take the good data that I have modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is a combination of my initial one using `tidyr` and `dplyr`, and of `@jogo`'s (now deleted) answer using base R `aggregate(drop = FALSE)`:

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = 
"    id year groupid
1   A1 2000      G1
2   A1 2000      G1
3   A1 2000      G1
4   A2 2000      G2
5   A1 2001      G1
6  A12 2001      G1
7  A13 2001      G1
8   A3 2001      G2
9  A33 2001      G2
10  A4 2001      G3
11  A4 2002      G3
12  A5 2002      G3
13  A5 2003      G2
14  A6 2003      G4")

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  aggregate(id ~ year + groupid, ., unique, drop = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(groupid) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(new_ids = mapply(setdiff, id, lag(id)),
         newid = lapply(new_ids, length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(year, groupid) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

#    year groupid           id  new_ids newid
# 1  2000      G1           A1       A1     1
# 2  2000      G2           A2       A2     1
# 3  2000      G3                           0
# 4  2000      G4                           0
# 5  2001      G1 A1, A12, A13 A12, A13     2
# 6  2001      G2      A3, A33  A3, A33     2
# 7  2001      G3           A4       A4     1
# 8  2001      G4                           0
# 9  2002      G1                           0
# 10 2002      G2                           0
# 11 2002      G3       A4, A5       A5     1
# 12 2002      G4                           0
# 13 2003      G1                           0
# 14 2003      G2           A5       A5     1
# 15 2003      G3                           0
# 16 2003      G4           A6       A6     1
```

*Edit*: explanations, answer to comment:

- The `, .,` part is to say `df` should be the second argument to `aggregate()`, not the first (see `help("%>%")`). But really it was to make it shorter, you'd be better off using a longer and more robust form with named arguments, like: `aggregate(formula = id ~ year + groupid, data = ., FUN = unique, drop = FALSE)`.
- The added `group_by()` is necessary to make the use of `lag()` consistent. Without groups, we'd take the risk that the ids of `2000, G2` are compared to those of `2003, G1` (consecutive lines after `aggregate()`). What we really want is `setdiff(..., lag(...` to happen inside a `groupid` group, with rows ordered by `year` (hence the probably unnecessary `arrange(year)`). The lack of this `group_by()` makes no difference on this example, but would probably make one on your real life data.

Comment: Very impressive. I was trying something with `expand.grid()` to get all the combinations. I still don't understand what your `, .,`does. And also, why do you need to use `group_by` since you get the expected resultats without in your first answer.

Comment: drop = FALSE is such an insanely powerful flag :)

Comment: @Aurèle Thanks a lot, makes me to learn more about dplyr package.